# How do you cite the images on your blog?

Tags: images, blog

I just created a blog through wordpress and there was a background that I used from http://subtlepatterns.com/

I also used two other images...so I'm just wondering, do I need to cite these images in some way? In other words...when we write an essay or something, we usually cite the sources that we use, right? How does that work for images on our website? Do I need to cite anything?

I would appreciate any help, because I'm really confused....

Comment: If you know some other StackExchange site where such questions are on topic, let me know and I'll talk to their mods and move it there if it's ok.

Comment: @kaiser Thanks...I think it would be appropriate here http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/website with the tag "website"

Comment: The SuperUser mods refused to take the question as it's off topic there as well. They pointed me to the [subtle patterns legal note](http://subtlepatterns.com/about/) and about what your question really is. As that link helps, I will close the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Frequently Asked Questions](http://subtlepatterns.com/about/) on subtlepatterns.com state:

> #### How do I credit you on my site?
>
> You can credit using a comment in your HTML or CSS code. Example for CSS:
>   `/* Background pattern from subtlepatterns.com */`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just have one more question (if you don't mind)...if I search for an image on google and then display it on my website (not as a background but a regular picture) do I need to cite anything?

Comment: @Erciyes: That's complicated. Generally, you're not allowed to use other people's work without their consent. Although, to my understanding, there are exceptions. On Google Image Search, you can check the search tools and under "usage rights" filter for images which you *can* reuse. It's always good to mention your source with images you use ("Google Image Search" is not a source).